# cgmath : implement Into<Rad<S>> for f32?

Tags: rust

I'm struggling with the [from_axis_angle](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.12.0/cgmath/struct.Matrix4.html#method.from_axis_angle) of the Matrix4 of the [cgmath crate](https://crates.io/crates/cgmath).

It seems that it is required that the `angle` parameter implements `Into<Rad>`, so how could I implement this for my f32 ?
So that I can call the function with a f32, like so :

```rust
pub fn rotate(&mut self, axis: cgmath::Vector3<f32>, angle: f32) {
    self.local_pos = self.local_pos * cgmath::Matrix4::from_axis_angle(axis.normalize(), angle);
}
```

I'm still new to rust and don't quite understand why this is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass `cgmath::Rad(angle)` as the `angle` argument.

The `Into<Rad>` requirement that seemed like a hurdle is actually intended to be helpful. The idea is for `angle` to accept an actual `Rad` (which trivially implements `Into<Rad>`), but also other types that are convertible to `Rad<S>`, such as `Deg<S>`.